# Excel File Open Macro

Tags: vba, excel, object, runtime-error

So I'm trying to create a Macro That will update a cell when the file is opened. I'm getting the 424 Error and so I tried to do a better job defining my code/object but It still wasn't succesfull. I think I'm missing/overlooking  something really easy but I can't figure it out and this is my first project so I'm trying to learn and gain a better understanding then just googling a segment of code that will work.

```
Private Sub Auto_Open()

    Dim Try1 As String
    Try1 = ActivateSheet.Cells(3, 2).Select
    Tryl = "-"

    ' My first attempt is shown below
    '
    'Sheets("Current Calc").Activate
    'ActivateSheet.Cells(3, 2).Value = "-"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got a typo in your commented code

What you have...

```
Sheets("Current Calc").Activate
ActivateSheet.Cells(3, 2).Value = "-"
```

What it should be...

```
Sheets("Current Calc").Activate
ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 2).Value = "-"
```

Also, I should mention you should avoid using `.Activate` and `.Select` unless necessary. With that being said, I'd suggest the below code instead...

```
Sheets("Current Calc").Cells(3, 2).Value = "-"
```

**EDIT:**

When using `Auto_Open`, Excel must be opened **MANUALLY** in order for the code to execute; thus if it is opened via VBA this event will NOT trigger. If you want an event to trigger via VBA as well as manually, I'd suggest using `Workbook_Open`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Once again typos and not knowing all my options are my down fall.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following sub:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim Try1 As String

    Try1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 2).Select
    Tryl = "-"

End Sub
```

Some advices:

1. write your code in lowercase. When you change a line, your code will change to upper and lower case automatically, this way you will detect if you have some typo error.
2. write a function or object ant type `.` This will open a dropdown list, this way you will also avoid typo error.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and the "best coding practices". I always want to keep learning and improving. Are you aware of any lists of VBA best coding practices that I could read up on?

Comment: Hello, it's a pleasure. You can read [Excel VBA Performance](https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2009/03/12/excel-vba-performance-coding-best-practices/) and [VBA Best practices](http://www.spreadsheet1.com/vba-development-best-practices.html)